# JQuery - global function call when server request sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner and have followed a blog to add the please wait animated gif to my test page. It works well.

The blog instructions say to add the following code to the form button to trigger the please wait animated gif:

```
onclick="ShowProgressAnimation();"
```

This is fine if there is one page and one button that a developer wants to trigger the please wait animated gif with a call to the server.

What if a site has say 40 pages and 10 buttons on each form. Would a developer have the add the above code to each button on every page? It seems like a lot of work.

**Is there a global jquery function that would trigger the please wait animated gif each time the user called the server for an action for the entire site?**

Comment: are you talking about ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use class like below one

**HTML CODE**

```
<button id="one" class="btn">ADD</button>
<button id="two" class="btn">DELETE</button>
<button id="three" class="btn">UPDATE</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$('.bnt').click(function(){
    // code to show your progress animation goes here
})
```

you just have to add `class` **btn** to show your progress animation

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ajax requests then you can use [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    //show gif
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    //hide gif
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to all of your buttons. Then use that class to trigger a common function that will show your progress gif.

Let's say you have 10 buttons across 10 pages of the form:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="showprogress" value="Click">

<input type="button" id="button2" class="showprogress" value="Click">

<input type="button" id="button3" class="showprogress" value="Click">
```

And the jQuery will be:

```
//This code should go in the head tag, between script tags
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.showprogress').on('click', function(e){
        //Show the gif image
        //Do the processing
    });
});
```